# Select from five tables using php mysql

Tags: mysql

I have five tables:

1. table1
2. table2
3. table3
4. table4
5. table5

In these tables a field is common, that is `name`.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1, table2, table3, table4, table5
WHERE table1.name = table2.name
    and table2.name = table3.name
    and table3.name = table4.name
    and table4.name = table5.name
```

Should such query work?

Comment: How will we know if your query works? Try it, tell us the error if you encounter one and we can help then. I prefer the `join...on` syntax.

Comment: It has nothing to do with PHP. Such query should work, but try it yourself and you will see. I just would recommend you to use JOIN instead.

Comment: BTW Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0):

Try this example and tweak it to your own liking.

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.*, T3.*, T4.*, T5.*
FROM TABLE1 T1 
JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.NAME = T2.NAME
JOIN TABLE2 T3 ON T1.NAME = T3.NAME
JOIN TABLE2 T4 ON T1.NAME = T4.NAME
JOIN TABLE2 T5 ON T1.NAME = T5.NAME
```